# How do you only display certain parts of a larger child div within a smaller parent div

Tags: html, css

So I have a div really larger then it's parent. I want it to only display what fits inside the parent and the rest not be hidden.

Comment: could you elaborate further and show your actual code? have you tried with `overflow: hidden` applied on the parent?

Comment: you seem to say something contradictory: you want "to only display what fits inside the parent" and yet you want "the rest not be hidden."

Comment: I can't see any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `overflow: hidden` on the parent `div`.

```css
div.outer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.inner {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel sapien pretium, faucibus nibh sit amet, pretium lacus. Etiam mollis nisl mi, et tempus elit accumsan ut. Nunc luctus eget mi nec ultricies. Etiam vehicula et lectus et condimentum. Mauris euismod at diam et facilisis. Cras et purus eget felis fermentum suscipit ut vitae purus. Curabitur consectetur blandit nibh, sed efficitur justo posuere id. Quisque aliquam, felis vel auctor pulvinar, urna mi condimentum tellus, in accumsan enim est ut mauris.
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, if you want it to scroll, use `overflow: scroll`:

```css
div.outer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  
  overflow: scroll;
}

div.inner {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel sapien pretium, faucibus nibh sit amet, pretium lacus. Etiam mollis nisl mi, et tempus elit accumsan ut. Nunc luctus eget mi nec ultricies. Etiam vehicula et lectus et condimentum. Mauris euismod at diam et facilisis. Cras et purus eget felis fermentum suscipit ut vitae purus. Curabitur consectetur blandit nibh, sed efficitur justo posuere id. Quisque aliquam, felis vel auctor pulvinar, urna mi condimentum tellus, in accumsan enim est ut mauris.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#wrapper { 
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#child {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="child">child</div>
  </div>
```